# How to pass date from application to cronjob in cpanel?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel

I have created the application in `CodeIgniter` and hosted in `cpanel`. I need to create a cron job for that application. But the date should be pass from my created application to the cron job.

Comment: check this https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/DD/cPanel+API+2+Functions+-+Cron%3A%3Aadd_line

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass anything to the cron job - it is static.

Set the cron job to execute your application for an example every hour. Then make your application check if the time of execution is the correct time. If it's not the time you need - then simply exit the application.
If it is the time you need, then execute your application.